# Thymeleaf + Spring MVC + Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I don't understand, how to change @Controller to @RestController for RESTFull serivce, if html template linked with attributes that I get in ModelAndView

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

   @GetMapping("/index")
   public ModelAndView index(){
      return new ModelAndView("/index", name, userService.getUser().getName());
   }
}
```

and in thymeleaf template it's look like

```
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
```

But I wanna go to index page, and in background get user name

```
@RestController
public class MyController{

   @GetMapping("/api/user")
   public String index(){
      return userService.getUser().getName();
   }
}
```

I can use ajax for update tag "p", but in this way it's nothing benefit of using thymeleaf, I can use jsp. So what the best way use thymeleaf with rest and is it rational?

Comment: Thymeleaf and JSP are used for **server-side rendering**. If you use REST + JavaScript (AJAX), you're working with **client-side rendering** and in that case you don't need Thymeleaf nor JSPs and you could serve plain static HTML files. Choosing between server-side rendering, client-side rendering or a hybrid model depends largely on the use case/scenario and there isn't a thing as a "best" way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the purpose of `Thymeleaf`is for server-side rendering. 
**Thymeleaf is a Java template engine for processing and creating HTML, XML, JavaScript, CSS, and text.** 
When you are using JSON API and parse the `JSON` and use angular or any other client-side rendering framework for that. ***Thymeleaf with REST is not the approach***.

But if you want to use both ways like provide data to `Thymeleaf` and also provide REST services to other application follow below approach.

```
@RequestMapping('/foobars')
abstract class FoobarBaseController {

    @RequestMapping
    abstract listAll()
}

@Controller
class FoobarHtmlController extends FoobarBaseController {
    @Override ModelAndView listAll() {
        new ModelAndView('foobars/foobarThymeleafTemplate', [foobars: foobarsList])
    }
}



 @RestController
    @RequestMapping('/foobars', produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

class FoobarJsonController extends FoobarBaseController {
    @Override Collection<Foobar> listAll() {
        foobarsList
    }
}
```

I hope this address your question properly.

Comment: how hard could it be for thymeleaf to call back a rest controller end point and thus avoid these complications? this way the back-end will be almost similar no matter what front-end you will use

Comment: @MihaiS Question is not about the back end only it's about How you will provide data to the front end in the best way based on front end technology. If you have JS frameworks then provide using REST API ( big trend in industry) or If you have server rendering technology then use MV object from spring framework. If you want to lets say provide both REST API to mobile devices or some other third party and Model view Object to internal server rendering technology.

Comment: If we take Question as words he mentioned without understanding intent then the answer is simply NO.

Comment: Is there any best practice for making the RestController or the Controller the base public class instead of the child class?